# Изменение типа столбца и конвертация данных

Tags: sql, postgresql

Есть столбец planned_duration, который хранит время в минутах и имеет тип integer. Необходимо сменить его тип на interval и преобразовать уже имеющиеся данные. Для этого я написал такой SQL-код:

```
ALTER TABLE shift ALTER COLUMN planned_duration TYPE INTERVAL USING planned_duration * INTERVAL '60 sec';
```

Но к сожалению это не работает. Я получаю такую ошибку:

> ERROR:  operator does not exist: interval >= integer HINT:  No
>   operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need
>   to add explicit type casts.

Что нужно сделать, чтобы корректно сменить тип столбца и преобразовать данные?

Comment: поставьте метку конкретного сервера. postgre / ms sql server / mysql?

Comment: Вариант - создать новый столбец, скопировать данные из старого, удалить старый столбец, переименовать новый столбец - не рассматривается?

Answer (score 3):

Проблема была в ограничении:

```
CONSTRAINT shift_planned_duration_check CHECK (planned_duration >= 0)
```

Решил проблему удалением этого ограничения перед изменением столбца:

```
ALTER TABLE shift DROP CONSTRAINT shift_planned_duration_check;
```